# how to make vuejs work fine with for loop of data and input select

Tags: django, vuejs3

i try many solution but problem when select one of choice change all another select option

```
 <div class="form-group" v-for="(service , index) in clinicThirdPartyServices" :key="index">
                <div class="form-group row mb-6">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label class="form-label">[[service.category]]</label>
                        <input  class="form-control form-control-solid"
                               :placeholder="[[service.category]]"
                        />
                        <input hidden class="form-control form-control-solid"
                               placeholder="{{ thirdparty.category }}" name="service_category"
                               value="{{ thirdparty.category }}"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label class="form-label">{% translate 'Service' %} </label>
                        <select
                                name="service_supplier" id="thirdparty.category"
                                aria-label="{% translate 'Service' %}"
                                data-placeholder="{% translate 'Service' %}"
                                 @click="getThirdPartyServices([[service.owner_id]])"
                                class="form-select form-select-solid fw-bolder">

                             <option   v-for="(item,index) in servicesOfThirdParty" :key="item.slug" :value="[[item.id]]">[[item.title]]</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                        <label class="form-label">{% translate 'Note' %}</label>
                       <input  class="form-control form-control-solid"
                               placeholder="{% translate 'Note' %}" name="service_note"
                               value=""
                        />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i need when select the one of choice select not change the another options to make code run fine

Comment: use  {{ item.id }} not [[ item.id ]] perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behavior where selecting one option does not change the selection of other options, you can use a separate variable for each select element to store its selected value.

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(service, index) in clinicThirdPartyServices" :key="index">
  <div class="form-group row mb-6">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="form-label">[[service.category]]</label>
      <input class="form-control form-control-solid" :placeholder="[[service.category]]" />
      <input hidden class="form-control form-control-solid" :placeholder="thirdparty.category" name="service_category" :value="thirdparty.category" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="form-label">{% translate 'Service' %}</label>
      <select name="service_supplier" :id="'thirdparty.category' + index" aria-label="{% translate 'Service' %}" data-placeholder="{% translate 'Service' %}" class="form-select form-select-solid fw-bolder" @click="getThirdPartyServices(service.owner_id)" v-model="selectedServices[index]">
        <option v-for="(item, index) in servicesOfThirdParty" :key="item.slug" :value="item.id">[[item.title]]</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <label class="form-label">{% translate 'Note' %}</label>
      <input class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="{% translate 'Note' %}" name="service_note" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


data() {
  return {
    selectedServices: [], // Array to store selected values for each select element
    // ...
  };
},
```